# Do any countries other than USA require passing immigration for in-transit travelers?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, layovers

Whenever I've been on a flight between two countries with a stop at a US airport, I've had to:

- Disembark.
- Go through immigration.
- Reclaim my checked baggage.
- Go through customs.
- Recheck my baggage.
- Pass back through airport security.

At any non-US airport, my baggage has automatically been transferred to the next plane and I've simply walked through the "safe area" of the airport to the new boarding gate.

This is especially annoying when the plane arrives late and there is very little time to get to the connecting flight.

Whenever possible I now avoid any routes that pass through that country.

Is the USA the only country that does this immigration thing?

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of [Are international transfer zones typical around the world?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/are-international-transfer-zones-typical-around-the-world)

Comment: Unfortunately, your assumption is incorrect. This does happen but is not the rule. It actually depends on the airport, when you go from South to North America via Atlanta for example, there is no need to claim and recheck luggage but if you pass via Miami instead, then you do. It depends on whether the airport is enabled for I2I (International-2-International).

Comment: The fact that the US consistently requires all arriving passengers to go through customs and immigration actually simplifies planning. In all other cases, as noted in the linked question, it depends on everything from what airline you fly to what time you arrive. You can do an international-to-international transit at London Heathrow without going through UK immigration, for example, but not at Edinburgh.

Comment: @Itai are you sure of this about Atlanta? This would make it quite an exception in the US...

Comment: Yes, I have done it many times, Ecuador or Peru to Canada. It's the reason we choose the slightly longer route (compared to Miami) when we have a lot of luggage.